# Minimal extension of local systems

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Let $M$ be a complex manifold of dimension $2$, $D \subset M$ be a connected, simple, normal crossings divisor and $L$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-local system defined over $M\backslash D$. Denote by $j: M\backslash D \to M$ and $i:D \to M$, the natural inclusions. Recall, there exists a minimal extension $j_{!*}L$ of $L$ to $M$ (this is the image of $j_!L \to j_*L$). Denote by $i^{-1}(j_{!*}L)$ the restriction of $j_{!*}L$ to $D$. Is there a necessary and sufficient condition under which the restriction $i^{-1}(j_{!*}L)$ is a local system on $D$?

Comment: Sorry, in my limited experience people usually want to prove that a constructible sheaf is a local system on a $\it smooth$ subspace. What is the motivation for having a local system on a the whole $\it singular$ subspace $D$ rather than on the smooth open part of $D$?

Comment: @YellowPig Do you have an answer for the question, if we replace $D$ by the smooth part of $D$?

Comment: I thought that on the smooth part of $D$ it's a local system because, looking at a transversal slice to $D$, you are taking the minimal extension of the monodromy around the divisor

Comment: @YellowPig can you suggest some reference/literature.